# Hide the column and show the field when edit or add in jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have more colimns in jqGrid . so  need to hide the some columns(fields) in jqGrod. When we edit or add need to show all fields in jqgrid edit popup or add popup.  So  is there any property for this.

**Code :**

```
    $("#Datasourcegrid").jqGrid({
              postData: { CAId: function () { return $('#hdnchnAppId').val(); } },
                colNames: ['DataSourceId', 'Title','Sort Order'],
                colModel: [
                            { name: 'DataSourceId', index: 'DataSourceId', align: 'left', key: true, editable: false, hidden: true, search:false,width: '10'},
                            { name: 'DataSourceTitle', index: 'DataSourceTitle', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '400',editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true },stype:'text', search:true,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq']}},
                            { name: 'SortOrder', index: 'SortOrder', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '100',editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: 'text', editrules:{number:true, required:true}, search:false},

 ],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `edithidden:true` to the `editrules` of the `hidden: true` column, check the [jqgrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules) on the editrules section for more options.